# VB.Net - Cannot create field "password" in Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, field, syntax-error

```
'Create field in table
Public Sub createField(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal fieldName As String, ByVal fieldType As String)
    If Not isConnected() Then
        XGUI.consolePrint("XAccessDatabase.createField() Warning - Database not connected. Create field canceled")
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim myOleDbCommand As OleDbCommand
    myOleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("ALTER TABLE " & tableName & " ADD COLUMN " & fieldName & " " & fieldType, connection)
    myOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Function

createField("users", "password", "TEXT(60)")                       'Password
```

I get: Syntax error in field definition, 
when I try to create "password" field.
In all other cases (other field names) it works fine.

When trying to create it manually with MS-Access, I have no problem either.
What is going on???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "ADD COLUMN [" & fieldname & "] "

Password is a reserved word.

Comment: [Password is a reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266), so I would say it is better to change the field (column) name, rather than having to constantly watch for it.

Answer (score 2):

`password` [is a keyword](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) for the Jet database engine. You should escape it by putting it in braces: `[password]`.